# Joint probabilities given three variables

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

Suppose that $X, Y , Z$ are independent random variables, each being uniformly
distributed over $[0, 1]$.

I'm being asked to find the probability that $Xa^2 + Ya + Z = 0$ has all real roots.

I just used the determinant and then isolated for $X$, 
That is: I found that if $Y^2-4XZ > 0$, then rewrote it as $X < \frac{Y^2}{4Z}$. Then since f(x) = f(y) = f(z) = 1, I triple integrated f(y) and f(z) from 0 to 1, and x from 0 to $\frac{Y^2}{4Z}$ and solved and got 1/24.... would that be the right process?

Comment: you might want to include mroe working so that we can verify? what does isolating $X$ mean?

Comment: You should integrate $x$ from $0$ to $\min\{1, \frac{y^2}{4z}\}$.